# How to display the view page including styles in mpdf in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have designed a view page in codeigniter including all the design styles. Also in that particular page, I have a download button for submitting the pdf file in the same view page in codeigniter. But when I am clicking on the download button, the pdf is being downloaded containing all the contents in the view page but it doesnot have all the design styles in the pdf. I am using mpdf plugin for downloading the pdf. Can anyone suggest how to include all the styles in the view into the pdf ?

First of all, the styles in the view page was given as external stylesheet but it didnot reflect in the pdf. After that I made all the external styles as inline. But it is not having any effect. Can anyone suggest a solution for this ?

Comment: mpdf currently only supports CSS2 and little more, so not all styles (like flexbox, grid, etc.) will be supported.

Comment: So..Is there any other plugins for this downloading pdf  which reflects all the design elements ?

Comment: mpdf are working on it, I have not found any opensource php library for pdf creation with CSS3 support